# Batch processing in QGIS SAGA Algorithm

Tags: qgis, interpolation, saga, batch

i'm struggling to run batch processing multilevel b-spline interpolation for my surface area the below error message keeps on poping up after the process>

```
Processing algorithm 1/3...
Algorithm Multilevel b-spline interpolation starting...
grid_spline "Multilevel B-Spline Interpolation" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -SHAPES "C:/Users/mlamli.v/Downloads/Trial3_B1_1_Site.csv.shp" -FIELD "2011-07-08 " -METHOD 0 -EPSILON 0.0001 -TARGET_USER_XMIN 19.2206320676 -TARGET_USER_XMAX 19.2230436656 -TARGET_USER_YMIN -34.0070661627 -TARGET_USER_YMAX -34.0056905999 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 1e-06 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "C:\Users\mlamli.v\AppData\Local\Temp\processing2e2280fd77be44ffa848faacde5e36a1\78ac882c583747e4a712f0ca8379c16d\TARGETOUTGRID.sdat"

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga-ltr

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\WBem;;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga-ltr;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>saga_cmd grid_spline "Multilevel B-Spline Interpolation" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -SHAPES "C:/Users/mlamli.v/Downloads/Trial3_B1_1_Site.csv.shp" -FIELD "2011-07-08
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: grid_spline
library : Spline Interpolation
tool : Multilevel B-Spline Interpolation
author : O.Conrad (c) 2006
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________

Load shapes: C:/Users/mlamli.v/Downloads/Trial3_B1_1_Site.csv.shp...




Parameters


Points: Trial3_B1_1_Site.csv
Attribute: 2011-07-08
Target Grid System: user defined
Cellsize: 0.000028
Left: 19.221356
Right: 19.222112
Bottom: -34.006392
Top: -34.005944
Fit: nodes
Method: with B-spline refinement
Threshold Error: 0.000100
Maximum Level: 11




level:1, error:17, max:46.947204, mean:24.872109


level:2, error:17, max:41.319060, mean:21.044483



level:3, error:17, max:31.586489, mean:13.923085



level:4, error:17, max:22.824775, mean:6.834893



level:5, error:17, max:9.743622, mean:2.226048



level:6, error:8, max:1.612531, mean:0.710186



level:7, error:2, max:0.002017, mean:0.001562



level:8, error:0, max:0.000000, mean:0.000000



C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>" -METHOD 0 -EPSILON 0.0001 -TARGET_USER_XMIN 19.2206320676 -TARGET_USER_XMAX 19.2230436656 -TARGET_USER_YMIN -34.0070661627 -TARGET_USER_YMAX -34.0056905999 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 1e-06 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "C:\Users\mlamli.v\AppData\Local\Temp\processing2e2280fd77be44ffa848faacde5e36a1\78ac882c583747e4a712f0ca8379c16d\TARGETOUTGRID.sdat"
The input line is too long.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>exit
Converting outputs
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details
```

Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 1):

In the Batch Processing window, we need to define the output grid (as `-TARGET_OUT_GRID`) along with **path to the file**.

Looking at the failed command, `-TARGET_OUT_GRID` was:

```
-TARGET_OUT_GRID "C:\Users\mlamli.v\AppData\Local\Temp\processing2e2280fd77be44ffa848faacde5e36a1\78ac882c583747e4a712f0ca8379c16d\TARGETOUTGRID.sdat"
```

which suggests that the filename was not given properly.

To set the output **Grid**, click on the ellipsis (three dots) <kbd>...</kbd>  button at the right-hand side, find a location (e.g. `C:/Users/your_username/Document`) to save your output, and give the filename so that the parameter reads like `C:/Users/your_username/Document/output1.tif`.